# jquery closest anchor in view port

Tags: jquery, html, css

i develop a one-page website where i want to allow 2 images in fixed position as a "joystick" to allow up-down navigation on `mouseover`, i can manage that easily with jquery `.scroll()` method and jquery [scroll To plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html%E2%80%8F)

on the page, i have several anchors, i want to have one more behavior - when a user clicks the up or the down arrow, i want the page to scroll to the closest anchor on the page - previous anchor when the user clicks on the "**up**" button and the closest down "**anchor**" when the user clicks the down arrow.

since my scroller is fixed positioned, the `.closest()` jquery method does not work. is there a way to figure out the closest anchors in the viewport?

**JS FIDDLE:**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/8vW6n/1/
```

any help shall be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is this what you wanted ? http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/8vW6n/15/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like that:

```
$(".joystick .down").click(function(){
    var anchors = $('.page > a');
    var anchorPositions = [];
    anchors.each(function(ind, anch){
        anchorPositions.push(anch.getBoundingClientRect().top);
    });
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<anchorPositions.length;i++)
        if(anchorPositions[i] > 0) break;

    console.log(anchors.eq(i));
    //anchors.eq(i) is the closest anchor
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3kTHa/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
    var index = 1;
    $(function () {
      $(".joystick .up").hover(function () {
       index--;
       anc = "#anchor" + index;
       if ($(anc).length) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(anc).offset().top
          }, 2000);
       } else {
          index++;
       }
    }, function () {
  });    
 $(".joystick .down").hover(function () {
    index++;
    anc = "#anchor" + index;
    if ($(anc).length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(anc).offset().top
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        index--;
    }
}, function () {
  });
});

$("#button").click(function () {
   $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

**JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/8vW6n/15/

Happy Coding :)